# Sass: how to manage blank space inside a single string of an array

Tags: arrays, string, variables, sass

I need to insert `'Roboto', sans-serif` as a single string of an array.
I tried something like that:

`$p: (2vw 4vw 3vw 4.5vw 'Roboto'+,sans-serif)`

but it doesn't work.
Any suggestion?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following method to create a list element that contains the special list delimiter characters like spaces or commas.

`unquote("'String', with random, delimeters")`